# Integrating the Gaussian kernel with absolute value

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

How do I integrate: $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|y|e^{\frac{-(\xi-y)^2}{4t}}dy,$$  in terms of of the error function, erf$(x)=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$. I have done some substitutions that result in things like $\int_{\infty}^z$ which I think does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|y|e^{\frac{-(\xi-y)^2}{4t}}dy$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{\frac{-(\xi-y)^2}{4t}}dy + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{0}(-y)e^{\frac{-(\xi-y)^2}{4t}}dy$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{\frac{-(\xi-y)^2}{4t}}dy - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{0}^{-\infty}(-y)e^{\frac{-(\xi-y)^2}{4t}}dy$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{\frac{-(\xi-y)^2}{4t}}dy + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{\frac{-(\xi+y)^2}{4t}}dy$$
Then, integrating by parts ($u = y$, $\mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{e}^{\dots} $) and using that $\mathrm{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t$, then performing the next pair of integrals by shifting $\xi$ away...:

$$=\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4t}} + \frac{\xi}{2}\left(1+\mathrm{erf} \frac{\xi}{2\sqrt{t}}\right) + \sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4t}} - \frac{\xi}{2}\left(1-\mathrm{erf} \frac{\xi}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$$
and this simplifies to 
$$=2\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4t}} + \xi\left(\mathrm{erf} \frac{\xi}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$$

Comment: I cannot see how the second integral is the same as the first

Comment: @Vaolter:  On the positive half, $|y|=y$.  On the negative half, $|y| = -y$.  Then, reversing the order of integration on the negative half, we get an additional minus sign and find that we can just double the integral on the positive half.

Comment: I understand how to split the integral, but if is make $z=-y$ in the second integral I get $\int_0^{\infty}ze^{-(\xi+z)^2/4t}$ which is different to the first integral

Comment: @Vaolter:  Not sure what integral you're trying to write, but I think I may have been hasty in cancelling negative signs...  Editing.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I could you add more steps to in the integration process and how you use the erf.

Comment: @Vaolter: Carpal tunnel is acting up.  Instead I reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions  :  $\int x \phi(a+bx)dx$  and also  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518281/how-to-derive-the-mean-and-variance-of-a-gaussian-random-variable/519631#519631  (which shows the two steps you're asking about in a slightly different order).