# Integration of Heat Equation

Tags: integration, heat-equation

how do i show that,

$$
u(x, t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_0^\infty y^2e^{-(x-y)^2/4t} \, dy = ( x^2+2t )N\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2t}}\right) + \sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}} xe^{-x^2/4t}
$$

where

$$
N(z)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^z e^{-p^2/2} \, dp
$$

[update]

I managed to get the answer by,

let $p=(x-y)/\sqrt{2t}$

then

$$
u(x, t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2t}}} (x-\sqrt{2t}p)^2e^{-(x-y)^2/4t} \, dy  \\= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2t}}} (x^2- 2\sqrt{2t}px+2tp^2)e^{-(x-y)^2/4t}\\=x^2N(x/\sqrt{2t}) -2\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}x\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2t}}}pe^{-p^2/2}dp+\frac{2t}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2t}}}p^2e^{-p^2/2}dp\\=x^2N(x/\sqrt{2t})+2\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}xe^{-x^2/4t}+\left(-\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}xe^{-x^2/4t}+2tN(x/\sqrt{2t})\right)\\=( x^2+2t )N\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2t}}\right) + \sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}} xe^{-x^2/4t}
$$

Comment: It would be instructive to look in a text on basic probability, because this problem basically comes down to finding the variance of a normal random variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to derive the mean and variance of a Gaussian Random variable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518281/how-to-derive-the-mean-and-variance-of-a-gaussian-random-variable)

Comment: For starters, let $u=\dfrac{x-y}{\sqrt{2t}}$.

Comment: sorry for not putting in enough details. i know about substituting $u=(x-y)/\sqrt{2t}$ but was wrestling with not being able to get the exact same answer due to some carelessness with manipulating terms. i'm able to get it now