# Standard Deviation of a Normal Distribution Graph

Tags: normal-distribution

I am learning about the student t-test.

I am struggling, however, to be given a reasonable explanation why the standard deviation of the standard normal distribution curve is 1.

It says "The Standard Normal Variable is denoted Z and has mean 0 and S.D 1..."

"... this is written as Z ~ N(0,1^2)

Can someone please explain?
Very much appreciate it.

Comment: It's hard to be sure what your question means. Suppose $X$ is normally distributed and has expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Let $Z = \dfrac {X-\mu} \sigma,$ so that $X = \mu + \sigma Z.$ Then $Z$ has expected value $0$ and standard deviation $1$ and is normally distributed. The one member of this family of distributions that has expected value $0$ and standard deviation $1$ is the one we call the "standard" one. $\qquad$

Comment: If you are asking how to find mean and standard deviation of random variable whose distribution has density $$f_{\mu,\sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \sigma^2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$ then see this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/518281/250955).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure what your question means. Suppose $X$ is normally distributed and has expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Let $Z = \dfrac {X-\mu} \sigma,$ so that $X = \mu + \sigma Z.$ Then $Z$ has expected value $0$ and standard deviation $1$ and is normally distributed. The one member of this family of distributions that has expected value $0$ and standard deviation $1$ is the one we call the "standard" one.

The distribution of $X$ is
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(1/2)\Big((x-\mu)/\sigma\Big)^2} \, \frac{dx} \sigma.
$$
If you let $z= \dfrac{x-\mu}\sigma$, then we have $dz=\dfrac{dx}\sigma$ and the measure becomes
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(1/2) z^2} \, dz.
$$
The expected value of that is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty z \left( \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(1/2)z^2} \, dz \right)
$$
and this is clearly $0$ because an odd function is integrated over an interval symmetric about $0$. The variance takes some work. Let's call it $\tau^2:$
$$
\tau^2 = \operatorname{var}(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2 \left( \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(1/2)z^2} \, dz \right).
$$
We have
$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = \operatorname{E}(\mu+\sigma Z) = \mu + \sigma\operatorname{E}(Z) = \mu+\sigma\cdot0 = \mu,
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{var}(\mu+\sigma Z) = \sigma^2 \operatorname{var}(Z) = \sigma^2\tau^2.
$$
If your question is how did we conclude that $\tau^2=1$, say so and maybe I'll post some more on that.

Answer (score 0):

The "standard normal distribution" has mean 0 and standard deviation 1 because that is in fact the definition of the "standard normal distribution". To understand this, what I think you need to understand is what a "normal distribution" in general is.

A "normal distribution" is a distribution of "relative frequency" $\Phi(x)$ with respect to a variable $x$ that is in a very specific shape, specifically
\begin{align*}
\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}},
\end{align*}
where $\mu$ and $\sigma>0$ are parameters for the mean and standard deviation, respectively.

As you've learned in statistics, the normal distribution has a "bell curve shape" (and you'll find $\Phi(x)$ has exactly the shape you've seen).

And like I said, the only thing special about the "standard normal distribution" is that the parameters are $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, hence having the equation $\Phi_s(z)=1/\sqrt{2\pi} \cdot e^{-z^2/2}$. I think the real question is "why is the standard normal distribution so useful?" It's useful because it gives an eloquent "$z$-score" measurement that captures how much "standard devations" a given point is from the mean.

Let's say the distribution $\Psi(x)$ of height (in feet) of all people in a classroom was the following normal distribution
\begin{align*}
\Psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(.5)}e^{-\frac{(x-5.5)^2}{2(.5)^2}},
\end{align*}
in other words $\mu=5.5$ and $\sigma=.5$. A height like $x=6$ ft may seem like quite a deviation from the mean, but how do we quantify how much of a deviation is it really? This is where the "standard normal distribution" comes in. Any point on a distribution with given mean and standard deviation parameters can be "normalized" into a $z$-score using the equation
\begin{align*}
z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma},
\end{align*}
which quantifies what the point is on the standard normal distribution $\Phi_s(z)$ (since the z-score by the defined equation above has $\mu_z=0$ and $\sigma_z=1$). And again, by design, the z-score tells us how many "standard deviations away" something is. So in our example, $6$ ft would be a height that has a $z$-score of $z=1$, meaning it is a single standard deviation from the mean.

Hope that helps. And here's the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) for more information (the introduction has an intuitive explanation worth the read). And in case you're curious as to how the $t$-distribution is analogous to the normal distribution, let's just say it converges to the normal distribution as an "additional parameter" (the degrees of freedom) gets very large. But I won't get ahead of myself, and wait for you to ask that if you're curious about that.