# Help understanding expected value proof of Gaussian distribution answer here

Tags: probability, integration, means, gaussian-integral

I was hoping someone could help me understand the first proof/answer given to this question (I can't make a comment on the post since I don't have a high enough reputation score, so I am posting here.):

[how to derive the mean and variance of a Gaussian Random variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518281/how-to-derive-the-mean-and-variance-of-a-gaussian-random-variable)

I follow the proof until the step that follows "and using again integral properties we have." Essentially, I don't fully understand this transition (quoted from the original post):

"$$I_1 = -\int_{0}^{-\infty}x\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}dx + \int_{0}^{\infty}x\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}dx$$

and using again integral properties we have

$$I_1 = \int_{0}^{\infty}(-x)\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{(-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}dx + \int_{0}^{\infty}x\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}dx$$"

It seems the negative sign was added inside the function contained within the integrand (I'll call it $f(x)\equiv x\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}$), which had the effect of changing the limits from 0 to $-\infty$ to 0 to $\infty$, but it seems the negative sign outside the function disappeared as well.  I don't understand how the negative sign disappeared here.  Isn't it the case that:

\begin{align*}
\intop_{0}^{-\infty}f(x)dx & =\intop_{0}^{\infty}f(-x)dx\\
\end{align*}

and not

\begin{align*}
\intop_{0}^{-\infty}f(x)dx & =-\intop_{0}^{\infty}f(-x)dx\\
\end{align*}

So, I am under the impression that the negative sign should have remained in front of the first integral of $I_1$.  Am I missing something or forgetting some integration rule? Perhaps something else is going on here that I'm just not seeing.  Can someone help me understand how the two $I_1$'s above are equivalent?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is wrong** 
$$\begin{align*}
\intop_{0}^{-\infty}f(x)dx & =\intop_{0}^{\infty}f(-x)dx\\
\end{align*}$$

---

Let's take this integral
$$\intop_{0}^{-\infty}f(x)dx$$

Substitute $x=-t$ thus $dx=-dt$

Also, x goes from 0 to $-\infty$  now t should go form 0 to $\infty$

thus integral becomes
$$\intop_{0}^{\infty}f(-t)  \cdot  (-dt)$$

thus

$$\intop_{0}^{-\infty}f(x)dx=-\intop_{0}^{\infty}f(-t)  \cdot  dt$$

Thus we can say that

$$\intop_{0}^{-\infty}f(x)dx=-\intop_{0}^{\infty}f(-x)  \cdot  dx$$

Comment: Duh!  Thank you sooooo much for this.  I have no idea what I have been thinking.  It's been a while since I've looked at any of this stuff and I'm a bit rusty on my Calculus.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!  It seems so obvious to me now!

Comment: Welcome I am happy that I helped you. did you understand fully?

Comment: 100% understood now!  I can't believe I missed this somehow.  Thank you again!  I'll accept your answer (but it says I have to wait 5 minutes before accepting)!

Comment: Ok no problem good luck