# Deriving the expected value of the normal distribution via a substitution

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to compute the expected value, E$[x]$, of a random variable $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. The density function of the normal distribution is
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\right), \ \ \ -\infty<x<\infty.$$

I am attempting to use the following substitution to help find the expected value:
$$y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\implies dx=\sigma\sqrt{2} dy \tag{1}.$$

The expected value is computed as
\begin{align}
\text{E}[x]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_X(x) \ dx \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\exp\left(-\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\right) \ dx \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\mu+\sigma\sqrt{2} y)\exp(-y^2)\ dy \ \ \ \ \text{(using substitution $(1)$)} \\
&=\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-y^2) \ dy \ + \ \sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y\exp(-y^2) \ dy \\
&=\sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left(\left[-\frac{1}{2}\exp(-y^2)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-y^2)}{y} \ dy\right).
\end{align}
I am unsure what this simplifies to (specifically how to deal with the final integral). I've noticed that the integrand is odd (does the integral simply cancel?).

Comment: [Try](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518281/how-to-derive-the-mean-and-variance-of-a-gaussian-random-variable)

Comment: @BruceET Thanks. I have read the solution and agree with the result. However, I'm wondering if my method will work. It seems the most intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution is terrible but it must work as well! the natural substitution is

$$Y=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$

Using this (in this case you are standardizing your Gaussian) the result is very easy.

Considering valid your procedure, reading your last but one passage, the sum is the following

$$\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot \sqrt{\pi}+0=\mu$$

this because the first integral is the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) (in the link you can find the easy proof too) and the second is the integral of an odd function over a symmetric domain around zero.

Comment: Would you suggest that I instead use the substitution $$Y=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}?$$ If it's easier, it's probably a good idea. It never occurred to me.

Comment: @MB the substitution I suggested you is the more natural but the passages are more or less the same as yours